# What is the best suited encoding for C++ source code

Tags: c++, encoding

Recently I moved the encoding of my c++ sources from ASCII to UTF-8 but I am not sure it's a good idea as I have some problems with literals and now thinking slowly I don't see any advantage.

What encoding would be considered standard or "best practice" in c++ sources? (my ides are VStudio and QtCreator but I suppose the question is generic)

Comment: ASCII is a strict subset of UTF-8. That is, every valid ASCII octet is encoded in UTF-8 in exactly the same way. So if your code were actually ASCII (and not something funky like Windows-1252), it should be able to be processed as UTF-8 with no changes.

Answer (score 3):

I would say UTF-8 is the right choice as long as all the implementations you're using support it.

The advantages are that you don't have to write every non-ascii character using the `\uXXXX` or `\UXXXXXXXX` escapes. Or if by 'ASCII' you really mean one of the various locale specific encodings/codepages, using UTF-8 has the advantage that it works across all locales and doesn't require developers to configure their (Windows) machine to a specific locale in order to build your source.

If you describe the issues you're having with literals I can probably help you solve them.

Comment: One of the thoughts I'm having now is that I'd never need to enter in source code a non ASCII character, the only reason I can think of would be typing some localized string literal but that would be a bad idea.

Answer (score 2):

Don't put non-ASCII characters in your source code. Then the encoding is irrelevant.

It's sad but true, for a cross platform project, that's the safest and sanest option.

Answer (score 2):

From 2.3.1 of the standard:

> Character sets [lex.charset]
>
> 1 The basic source character set consists of 96 characters: the space character, the control characters representing horizontal tab, vertical tab, form feed, and new-line, plus the following 91 graphical characters:
>
> a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z
>
> A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z
>
> 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
>
> _ { } [ ] # ( ) < > % : ; . ? * + - / ^ & | ~ ! = , \ " ’